# Angular Karma tests fail to execute with "Found 1 load error" when using --watch=false

Tags: angular

We're getting an execution failure when running `ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless --watch=false --code-coverage`. The issue seems to be from `--watch-false`, because it executes when that argument is removed or set to true. The error log doesn't give me much helpful information unfortunately. We're using Angular 16.0.2

**Error log:**

```
30 06 2023 09:48:13.860:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
30 06 2023 09:48:13.869:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
30 06 2023 09:48:13.876:ERROR [karma-server]: Error: Found 1 load error
    at Server.<anonymous> (<PROJECT_DIRECTORY>\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:243:26)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at Server.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at emitListeningNT (node:net:1774:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-sonarqube-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
    subdir: '.',
     dir: 'report/coverage',
     reporters: [
        { type: 'lcov'},
        { type: 'text-summary'}
      ]
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'report/junit',
      outputFile: 'junit-report.xml'
    },
    sonarqubeReporter: {
      basePath: 'src/app',
      outputFolder: 'report/junit',
      filePattern: '**/*.spec.ts',
      encoding: 'utf-8',
      legacyMode: false,
      reportName: 'sonar-report.xml'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit', 'sonarqube'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
        ]
      }
    },
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

Is there any config I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: yes, iirc it came from either a failing test or a compile failure within a spec file. If you just run `ng test` without any arguments, fix any tests that are failing. The reason I thought it had to do with the `--watch-false` arg was because it ends the script when it runs into a failure, but omitting that arg will point you to where the error is a bit easier